# Understanding when a graph represents a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

Which of the following is the graph of a function where $y = f(x)$?

[image]

[image]

I got the answer for the above question is

> A function has one output for each input in its domain. Each $x$-value on this graph corresponds to only one $y$-value. So the answer (c) is correct.

Can anyone explain the answer properly? I did not understand the answer from a single line.

Comment: Could you be specific about what part of the stated answer you do not understand?

Answer (score 1):

In the first graph, if you take $x=1$, which $y$-value does it correspond to?   If you draw a vertical line through $x=1$, that line hits two points on the curve.  So there are two different $y$-values associated to $x=1.$   This contradicts the phrase in your answer "only one $y$-value." So (a) is not the answer.

If you can draw any vertical line and hit two or more points, then the picture is not the graph of a function.